# Correct number is not being displayed in the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Problem:

In the "Number of Answers" textbox, it should display the number 1, but it doesn't, it displays the number 2 and the reason it is displaying this number is that before the buttons changed, you selected 2 letter buttons, so it displays 2 in the textbox because you previously chose 2 letter buttons.

Now this is happening because of this code:

```
$('.answertxt', context).val(context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length > 0 ? context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length : '');,
```

in the `$('.gridBtns').on('click', function()` but I do need this code.

The reason I need this code is because lets say there is 7 letter buttons "A-G" and you turn on all the letter buttons, the textbox would display number "7", but if I change my mind and I want to only display 5 letter buttons "A-E", then the textbox would change from "7" to "5" as now only 5 buttons are turned on. That is why I need this code.

So my question is that if the user has clicked on the "Add" button, how can I get the number from the "Number of Answers" column within the row added be displayed in the textbox?

Below is the code I have where it is suppose to display the number within the textbox when the "Add" button is clicked on but it is over written because of the `"$('#btn'+gridValues).trigger('click');"` and in that code is the

```
$('.answertxt', context).val(context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length > 0 ? context.find('.answerBtnsOn').length : '');,
```

in the `$('.gridBtns').on('click', function()`

```
function addwindow(numberAnswer, gridValues, btn) { 

        $('#mainNumberAnswerTxt').val(numberAnswer);
        $('#btn'+gridValues).trigger('click');

}
```

Comment: so what's the actual problem?..

Comment: @MikhailKozhevnikov If you follow the steps, before you click "Add" button within the row, look at the "Number of Answers" column within that row, it states "1" but when you add it, the textbox displays "2", it shud b "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the important question is: why do you have to specify the number of answers AND the set of possible answers in the first place? That's redundancy. And if you want to have this sort of redundancy and keep it consistent at all times, you have to define constraints to do so, e.g. identify one of the things as primary -- either the textbox should always display the number of pressed buttons (and therefore be read-only) or (not really likely) the number of pressed buttons should always equal the number in the text box.

Allowing the user to edit the two independently is bound to cause inconsistency of the type you describe, even without the 'Add' button. I mean, I can type "2" and then go ahead and mark all the answers as possible.

Comment: That is because in the demo I did not include the validation, in my full application, there is a validation where if the user types in 2 in the textbox and the number of buttons selected is beyond or less than the number in textbox, then it will display an alert. To be honest I am thinking of changing it to what you have said, make it red only and everytime a button is elected, add it onto the textbox.

Comment: I will improve my code/demo and try and do the read only textbox thing you have stated and then come back to you if this problem still needs fixing. If there is no problem then I will mark your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a custom attribute to the .gridBtns elements that specify who triggered the click button so that when the user click on the .gridBtns element you can use the $(this).attr("cutom attribute name") and use this value to check who triggered the action and you would react based on that.

Comment: Can you give me an example on what you mean so I know how and where to code it please :)